# How to force a hard refresh after jQuery submit (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to upload a picture to a server. Once the upload is finished, the page automatically refreshes. All is well in FF, Chrome etc, but in IE the new page is not updated with the new photo. This behaviour is by design: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237885

Is there a way to force a hard refresh after a jQuery.submit?

Comment: Random querystring on the url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a query string with timestamp to an image url, like so:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg?1234567890"/>
```

This will force to clear the all browsers cache.

Comment: it's desirable to add a timestamp when the image was uploaded, to be able to cache this image until new one isn't uploaded again.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your webserver to emit no-cache headers for that particular image; but that will effect every client on every request, and so is not ideal.

The best solution would be to change the URL of the resource; either in JavaScript or on the server. Adding a query string to the URL will be enough to force a refresh... e.g change:

```
/my_image.jpg
```

to

```
/my_image.jpg?version=2
```

To generate a number, you could use the timestamp (`(new Date()).getTimestamp()` in JavaScript), or a random number (`Math.random() * 1000000`).

A complete JavaScript solution would be to add a class to the image you want to refresh (e.g. `force-reload`), and to put the `src` as a `data-` property instead;

```
<img class="force-reload" data-src="/my_image.jpg"/>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();

    $('img.force-reload').prop('src', function () {
        return $(this).data('src') + "?" + now;
    });
});
```